# How to change language of a specific application?

Tags: 11.10, language-support

Is it possible to change the language of a particular application so that when opened it shows in Spanish for example while the rest are in English?

I have Spanish and English installed in Ubuntu and am using English as the default one but I would like a way to change the language for a particular application without having to change the whole language of the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one line:

```
LANGUAGE=es_ES gedit
```

(please notice I am using Linux Manjaro, in this case the variable is called `LANGUAGE`)

Comment: I just tested this and it worked beautifully for a bunch of apps. Kudos Luca.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the `LANG` environment variable in a terminal. After that, all the applications that you launch with the new environment will follow that new locale. For example:

```
gedit # Will use default locale (English in your case)
export LANG=es_ES
gedit # Will use Spanish (provided it's installed)
```

If you don't get the Spanish translations for the application, then:

- Use `locale -a | grep es` command to verify that Spanish is already available.
- Try to set `LANG` to the full string returned by `locale -a`, that is, `es_ES.utf8` instead of just `es`.
- Use the `locale` command to verify the values of your locale environment variables. Depending on your configuration it might happen that `LANG` is being shadowed by `LC_ALL` or `LANGUAGE` environment variables. To fix that, you could set `LC_ALL` or `LANGUAGE` directly.

More information about locale environment variables can be found in the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) and in the [gettext manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/Locale-Environment-Variables.html).

Comment: Please note that for gettext compatible applications you need to set LANGUAGE instead of LANG. See example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have normally Swedish as the session language, but want the terminal in English. I achieve it with this file:

```
$ cat ~/bin/gnome-terminal
#!/bin/sh
export LANGUAGE=en_US
exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal $@
```

The file is chmod'ed with +x. With this method gnome-terminal is displayed in English irrespective of how start it - via graphical icon or via command line.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, neither `LC_ALL` or `LANG` environmental commands worked (in Lubuntu) by setting the specific language encoding such as

```
LC_ALL=el_GR.UTF-8 vlc
export LANG=el_GR.UTF-8
```

but I was able to set the language for the applications that I would like to run by using export and the generic name of the language. I had not installed it using locale-gen greek or anything similar with intention - I installed only `el_gr*` and similar versions.

Nontheless, the following worked for me - I run that command and then the desired application. Its language interface changed from the default one to the specified one:

```
export LANG=greek
```

and then you may return to default language of Linux system by writing:

```
 export LANG=c
```

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a terminal application, you could set up an alias. I use GB English as my default language but our git repo server only runs on US English. So i added this alias:

```
alias git="env LC_ALL=\"en_US.UTF-8\" git"
```

You could add it to your `.bashrc` or your `.aliases` list if you use that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

LANGUAGE=en_US:en
gedit
```