# Can I permanently change the GUI language of a certain program to English?

Tags: gui, language-support, locale, system-language

Is it possible to make a permanent change to the GUI language of Cola Git GUI or `git gui`? I would like to have them both in English, whenever I start them.

Is this possible?

I know of the following threads:

- [How to change language of a specific Application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79319/possible-to-change-language-to-a-specific-application)
- [Is it possible to change language for user interface temporarily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246547/is-it-possible-to-change-language-for-user-interface-temporarily)

but those feature ad-hoc solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you start it. Without knowing anything about the particular programs you mention, a generally convenient method is to put a small wrapper program in the `~/bin` folder.

To show you what I mean, I wrote such a wrapper to start `gedit` in Swedish (while I otherwise use English as my display language). The name of the file is `~/bin/gedit`, and this is its contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANGUAGE=sv
export LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
exec /usr/bin/gedit "$@"
```

The file shall be executable:

```
chmod +x gedit
```

HTH

Comment: I usually start programs via the bottom bar on my screen (I use Xfce, the bottom bar is hidden by default) or Synapse, the latter being in use 99% of the time.

Comment: It works. It's not true to the word, btu true in spirit and that's enough. :)

Comment: @henry: Glad to hear that.